# Allow MathML Tags in Jodit 3

Tags: mathjax, jodit

Is is possible to ignore tags from MathML without cleaning them?  For example:

```
<math>...</math>
```

There is an external (MathJax) renderer for the tag.

What happens now is that Jodit (v3) renders the entire formula tag set as some sort of ampersand entity. It would be good if the allowTags or something similar would cause Jodit to just leave the tag alone.